# Can I take my feral cat to my new home?

Tags: cats, feeding, feral, shelter

About 3 years ago I spotted a feral cat coming at night to my backyard.  I started putting food out for her.  I set up trap and took her to the vet to get her fixed.  Came to find out she already was so I released her.  She would run to hide every time she would see me or any light.  2 years later (about a year ago) she started coming to my yard when she would see me putting food out.  Little by little she has trusted me, not fully but enough to pet her.  She now comes out when the sun is setting.  During the winter I tried to put her in the garage and it didn’t workout, she is still feral.  Not extreme as when I trapped her but she definitely has trust issues. I plan to move in about 6 months and my heart breaks thinking of leaving her behind.  If I trap her and release her in my new neighborhood, will she be able to adjust? 
I have no experience with cats so your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**I'd say you shouldn't.**

- She doesn't even let you touch her. If she has problems in the new place, she can't ask help from you.
- She might be too old to compete with the other cats from scratch. Now, she should have a territory of her own, and it is easier to defend than claim new one.
- She might have other people giving out food.

The best you can do is to contact the neighbours to offer food at least from time to time, at a point close to your current feeding point. Even if they do it one-two times a week, it would help the cat a lot. Also, try to contact the new residents of your place, you never know when you meet a cat lover.

The odds are stacked against moving the cat, but it doesn't matter much. Bad things happen to feral cats all the time and it might happen to her whether you move her or leave her.

I hope this helps.

Comment: and even if op were successful in catching the cat and releasing it in a new environment, the cat's likely to just pack up and leave, trying to find its old hunting grounds. That's why it's always advised to leave cats indoors for a period of time after acquiring or moving them to let them acclimate and get a new claim on territory before allowing them outside.

Comment: @jwenting I agree. She'll look for familiar scents or scenes, unable to hunt or fend herself, with no human to help her. It looks bleak